# The problem with Java Runtime Exec on Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to dockerize a Java application with GDAL package (for ogr2ogr command).

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:10
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3-gdal
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal28
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-perl-doc
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-perl
RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-dev
RUN apt-get -y install gdal-data
RUN apt-get -y install gdal-bin

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

In Java code running on container there is a snippet:

```
String command = "ogrinfo PG:\"host=host.docker.internal user=postgres dbname=test password=postgres\"";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Then, output is:

```
Unable to open datasource `PG:"host=host.docker.internal' with the following drivers.
```

But, when I tried to run command on the container directly from bash, it becomes successful:

```
root@7b5fb10431cf:/# ogrinfo PG:"host=host.docker.internal user=postgres dbname=test password=postgres"
INFO: Open of `PG:host=host.docker.internal user=postgres dbname=test password=postgres'
      using driver `PostgreSQL' successful.
```

Why does such a difference exist?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the connection String is important [PostgreSQL / PostGIS](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html), Probably the problem is in the Process instance [Java Runtime.exec](https://www.programmersought.com/article/50971434216/).
the PG command must be run in the same way as you did directly in the container, this should works for you :

```
String connection = "\"host=host.docker.internal user=postgres dbname=test password=postgres\"" ;
String[] commands = {"bash","ogrinfo","PG:"+connection};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not execute "bash" command. Without "bash" command, I received same response.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hajed.Kh's answer, I tried this and it worked:

```
    String[] commands = {
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            command
    };
```